# How to save the whole scrollable UITableView to PNG

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, png

I would like to save the whole UITableView to a PNG file.

With this code, I managed to save the visible part:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(tableView.layer.frame.size, false, 0.0);
tableView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
let documentsURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
let imageURL = documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("cached.png")
data!.writeToURL(imageURL, atomically: false)
```

But I would also like the scrollable parts which are not currently shown.

Any idea?

Comment: How can you screenshot something which is not rendered on the screen at all? Interesting though. Maybe scroll it programmatically while taking screenshots all the way? Crude yup but thats all I can offer.

Comment: how big is it? can you load it all in memory at the same time?

Comment: I would scroll to the last visible cell + 1 (if it exist) do screenshot, add to image, and would do that till the last visible cell + 1 doesn't exist.

Comment: @NSNoob, on Android, you can get the whole View, even the non visible parts. I would like to do the same thing in iOS

Comment: @Wain, yes, I can load it all in memory, it's not too big

Comment: Fun. I am eagerly waiting to see a solution to this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are some [Swift extensions files](https://github.com/davidman/DHSmartScreenshot/tree/master/Classes/Swift) you can add to your project to make screenshots:

The new code would be:

```
let image = tableView.screenshot
let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
let documentsURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
let imageURL = documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("cached.png")
data!.writeToURL(imageURL, atomically: false)
```

Comment: interesting, I would need the same for Swift

Comment: @DanieleB did you see the [swift equivalent] for those categories? (https://github.com/davidman/DHSmartScreenshot/tree/master/Classes/Swift) for this?

Comment: it actually works really great!!!! I copied the 4 extensions files to my project and I just called `let image = tableView.screenshot` to get the UIImage, which I can then convert to PNG. Great library!!!!!

Comment: I just made an edit to the answer to include the new resulting code